# how to execute external commands from (Xe)(La)TeX?

Tags: xetex, external-files, shell-escape

i'm trying to capture output from an external command in a XeLaTeX document. as per https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20566/28067 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8929976/256361, i'm specifically doing

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

A A A

\immediate\input{|"node -v"}

B B B

\end{document}
```

i'm running TeX with `xelatex --enable-write18 --enable-pipes write18.tex` to enable features normally blocked (because security).

however, this does not appear to work. i've tried the `\input` command with and without the braces, and with and without `\immediate`, but as long as that line is in the source, XeLaTeX concludes output with

```
(./write18.aux
)
```

rather than

```
(./write18.aux) )
Output written on write18.pdf (1 page).
Transcript written on write18.log.
```

(ie there is an additional newline, and output just stops dead without the remaining lines). observe that on my system, the output of `node -v` is the completely un-dangerous string `v0.11.7`. i understand that in order to capture more arbitrary output i'd have to fiddle with catcodes, but that's food for another question.

so what am i doing wrong here?

**Update** @egreg you might be right! i tried

```
\immediate\write18{node -v > /tmp/temp.dat}
\input{/tmp/temp.dat}
```

and that did work. funny though it would appear you told readers in a comment to https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20566/28067 that "in TeX Live 2013 the syntax `\input|"command"` is supported also by XeTeX"–were you in error here?

btw the fact that (in TeXLive) using non-supported command line options do not seem to trigger error messages does not exactly help make testing easier. also funny that http://docs.miktex.org/manual/xetex.html has all the long options prefixed with two dashes where `xelatex --help` gives them with a single dash (and fails to even mention that many more options are available).

Comment: Unfortunately, the pipe doesn't seem to work on XeTeX.

Comment: You are using `xelatex`. Latex redefines `\input` and so - as mentioned in the first question you are linking too - you must use `\makeatletter\@@input|"..."`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer i'm trying to get that working but seemingly can't. if you're confident, mind to share a MWE with the rest of us?

Answer (score 3):

I used this

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\@@input|"dir"

\end{document}
```

which gave me some errors as the output of `dir` also contains a path with a backslash but beside this did what was expected: I got 12 pages of more or less sensible output (my test folder is large ;-)). I called xelatex with `--enable-pipes --shell-excape`. It worked with miktex and TL 2013 on windows. (`--enable-pipes` is not known in texlive but did no harm).

Comment: see, that's the difference—i'm working on OSX, not on windows. doing the exact code you gave (with `ls` substituting `dir`) i get the behavior described in my question. i'm not surprised that miktex behaves differently, but that TeXLive is si different on different OSes is new to me.

Comment: Gotta love the test folder. `:)` Currently mine has 384 files (per `ls -1 | wc -l`) `:)`

Comment: I tried it with the command `\@@input|"ls -l"` on MacOS X 10.14.5 (command line: `xelatex --shell-escape test.tex` and it worked (xelatex version `XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live 2019)`). There doesn't seem to be a `--enable-pipes` command line option.