# How to run shell command with \write18?

Tags: pdftex, miktex, shell-escape

I want to use the command `\write18` with shell or other excutables rather than only a restricted list of programs as it says here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20446/92620

How can i bypass the restrictions set on `\write18` to execute external/shell from documents ?

**EDIT:**

I got this line from the log file:

> runsystem(cmd.exe)...disabled (restricted).

```
\documentclass{report}
\immediate\write18{cmd.exe}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Run `pdflatex` (or other engine) with the `-shell-escape` option.

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: @egreg i already tried `-shell-escape` same as with `--enable-write18` i believe it's double hyphen  -- `pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode --shell-escape %.tex`, shell didnt run. @Bernard TexMaker

Comment: Did you configure TeXmaker to use the `--enable-write18` switch for `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Bernard yes i did

Comment: For me it works fine   with `auto-pst-pdf` and pstricks files. Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: @Bernard done. i dont see any instance of command line launched during/after compilation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40192/discussion-between-bernard-and-guest00).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that cmd.exe was ever directly allowed (in restricted mode). You need to run your document with `--shell-escape`.

When I try your document I get a prompt in the window where pdflatex compiled the document.

If you want a new cmd.exe windows you should probably use

```
\immediate\write18{start cmd.exe}
```

(again --shell-escape is needed).