# pdflatex: I am trying to show a page from pdf. Before i want to show, i want to check whether a word is present or not

Tags: pdftex

I am trying to show a page from pdf.

Before i want to show it using

/includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{./latex/test.pdf,2}

I want to check whether a word is present in `page 2` of `test.pdf` or not. Based on that i want to do some changes

Is this possible

Comment: I assume you mean `\includepdfmerge` but you give no indication of how that is defined, it is not a command I recognise. pdftex normally has no access to the internal structure of the pdf.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\includepdfmerge` is defined in [`pdfpages`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) package.

Comment: A really indirect proposal: use Python's [pdfminer](https://pypi.org/project/pdfminer/) to scrape the content of pdf for you. Therefore you should: 1) [execute shell command (your Python script) from LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311084/how-to-run-shell-command-with-write18) 2) check whether the word is present with your script and save result to a file 3) read and parse the result with LaTeX. Or, if you are using LuaTeX, you can invoke Python from Lua.

Comment: ` read and parse the result with LaTeX` ( how to do this)