# How to delete a file in latex code?

Tags: tex-core, filesystem-access

How to delete a file in latex code with normal complie tex. I create temporary files and when i finish using them I want to delete them. It not delete by bash or editor.
Thankyou!

Comment: TeX cannot delete files. You have to use a extension like [`\write18`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/what-are-immediate-write18-and-how-does-one-use-them) to call an external program/shell to delete a file.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Deleting external/auxiliary files?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/5764)

Comment: I'd be wary of deleting files via shell-escape. Until you're ready to clean up you want them around; e.g., if you are doing cross-referencing or a bibliography deleting the .aux file between runs will not get you what you want. I believe most editors that act as front ends for running TeX also have a clean command (e.g., maybe called Trash AUX Files).

Comment: The question _sounds_ like a duplicate of the question [Deleting external/auxiliary files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24785/5764) that Werner posted, but none of the answers there actually address it. @Schweinebacke can you just post your comment as an answer? This seems like a useful question and answer to have around, for future reference.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR For an answer I'd need to know the system, the format and eventually the used engine. So: No, I cannot give a real answer. But feel free to do it.

Comment: @Werner Not delete ".aux,.log,..." by bash or editor or complie command. In "normal complie" by code in latex. Thanks for answer but read full my question, please.

Comment: Can you give an example of a file type you would like to delete?

Comment: @samcarter It's text file. This problem is too old. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the cool latex automation tool `arara` to automatically delete the text file after the compilation is finished:

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: clean: { files: [ foo.txt ] }

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
content...
\end{document}
```