# \includegraphics with transparent

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, includegraphics, transparent

### Description

I wanted to create a PDF with resource images (square).
With this resource image (See below), it contains transparent space. I use `\includegraphics` to include an image.

But when I compile, it contains an edge line (below the dolphin) between transparent and actual images appeared on the output. (See image)

### Questions

How can I remove this edge or import in without it.

### Tex (MikTex / xetex)

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
 \usepackage{pst-all}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{grffile}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[paperheight=69.1mm,paperwidth=69.1mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthMM}{60.3}
 \newcommand{\Unitmm}{mm}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthPTx}{171.57011811736}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthPTy}{175.07011811736}

 \begin{document}
    \hspace*{-5.32mm}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw= black,line width=0.1mm, minimum size=69mm] at (0mm,0mm) () {};
    \node[circle,
    text=white,
    minimum size=60mm,
    path picture={
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){
            \begin{picture}(\imageWidthPTx,\imageWidthPTy)
            \fbox{\includegraphics[width=\imageWidthMM\Unitmm,angle=0]{**PATHTOIMAGES**}}
            \end{picture}
        };
    }]  at (0mm,0mm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

#### Resources file

[image: Resources]

#### The output PDF

[image: Output PDF]

Comment: You can clip the image.  Would that suffice?

Comment: I try to avoid that because I will have many of resource files in the same size but they can put an object around. (Otherwise I have to control its X,Y positioning one by one)

Comment: Just curiosity, why do you use a `picture` and `fbox` around `\includegraphics`? You could use `\includegraphics` inside node contents.

Comment: For a pdf with images, may be you want to look at [`incgraph`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/incgraph)

Comment: the surprising thing is not the line at the bottom, but why are there not lines on all four edges, as you have `\fbox` around the image.

Comment: A non-TeX solution (at least on Ubuntu) could be to use `convert` with the `-flatten` option on the command line. This replaces transparent pixels with white pixels. A full command would be `convert -flatten <input>.png <output>.png`.

Comment: Remove the \fbox.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see top and bottom lines, even without `\fbox`, just with `\includegraphics` inside the node.

Comment: @Ignasi They're just artefacts, though. If I zoom in, they disappear. Or if I zoom out, also they disappear.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you look to the resource image you will found out that is square and has transparent on top and bottom.

The lines are edges between them.

Comment: @Ignasi I print it out to sticker and the artifact was there.

Comment: @ZenithS I don't know if the lines are artifacts. A file with just `\includegraphics{whale}` show top and bottom lines. I can see them in TeXworks pdfviewer, Sumatrapdf and AdobeReader. Sometimes top and bottom lines are shown, sometimes only one of them, sometimes they desappear and on a larger zoom they appear again. I think this is a problem with the original image.

Comment: I also provide the raw images there, and it's look ok to me

Comment: If the problem is with the transparent part of the image, could you just flatten them all in one go with ImageMagick?

Comment: Something like: `mogrify -flatten /path/to/resources/*.png` This removes the lines in the whale image for me.

Comment: Using transparent pngs in pdf documents is not only a problem in LaTeX. I get the same problem when I import the image from the question in a LibreOffice Writer document and export as pdf. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35182147/tcpdf-gray-outline-on-transparent-png.

Comment: I am not sure why, but I could not reproduce your error, it works on my laptop.

Comment: @ZenithS - "I will have many of resource files in the same size but they can put an object around." Can you clarify your overall objective here? As some people have suggested, there may be non-TeX solutions to automating background removal, which may solve your problem, as nox has shown, and I can confirm.

Comment: The best solution as suggested before is to flaten your images before to use them. But if you don't want that, I can't see why, you can remove your `{picture}` environment and your `fbox` and add the options `[...,trim=0mm 70mm 0mm 70mm, clip]` to `\includegraphics`. The whale is at the same position and with the same size, so no difference, but without the lines.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution

This is possible by calling [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) within TeX (simplified MWE):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
\immediate\write18{convert whale.png -transparent white tmp.png}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw=black,line width=0.1mm,minimum size=70mm] at (0mm,0mm){};
    \node(img){\includegraphics[width=70mm]{tmp.png}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Compile

I compiled the document (`tmp.tex`) using:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape tmp.tex
```

where:

1. the flag `--shell-escape` allows `pdflatex` to call a system command (see 2.)
2. `\write18` executes its argument as a system command; `\immediate` makes sure this happens before `\includegraphics` requests the result ([more info here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20444))
3. `convert` invokes ImageMagick and replaces all `white` in `whale.png` with `-transparent`, writing the output to `tmp.png`

### Result

[image]

### Linux vs Windows (MikTeX) issues

- on Windows: `\write18` must specify the full path to ImageMagick, which typically looks like: `"C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-7.0.8-Q16/magick.exe"` instead of `convert`
- using MikTex: the flag to allow `\write18` is `--enable-write18` instead of `--shell-escape`
- using MikTex: `\write18` is blocked from running programs like `magick.exe`. There are supposedly options to bypass this security feature ([see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37489)) but none of them worked for me...

... as a result, I'm unable to reproduce the solution on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

Your picture has at the top and at the bottom a transparent background. But the background in the middle is white. What you see is the border. You could try to draw over this border a white line:

```
\documentclass{article}
 \PassOptionsToPackage{cmyk}{xcolor}
 %\usepackage{pst-all}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{grffile}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage[paperheight=69.1mm,paperwidth=69.1mm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthMM}{60.3}
 \newcommand{\Unitmm}{mm}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthPTx}{171.57011811736}
 \newcommand{\imageWidthPTy}{175.07011811736}

 \begin{document}
    \hspace*{-5.32mm}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node [circle, draw= black,line width=0.1mm, minimum size=69mm] at (0mm,0mm) () {};
    \node[circle,
    text=white,
    minimum size=60mm,
    path picture={
        \node at (path picture bounding box.center){%
            \includegraphics[width=\imageWidthMM\Unitmm]{whale}
        };
        \draw[white,line width=2pt] ([xshift=-30.15mm,yshift=-17mm]path picture bounding box.center)rectangle
                   ([xshift=30.15mm,yshift=17mm]path picture bounding box.center); 
    }]  at (0mm,0mm) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}

 \end{document}
```

But there is imho no guarantee that such artefacts don't appear again at other zooms or when you print.

Comment: Thanks I have no time to test it yet but that's possible

Answer (score 2):

I was curious because I have never had problems and Latex should be able to do this. So I experimented with it and... I don't know why the white background in the middle of your picture is creating those problems, but if you delete it by hand and replace it by transparent background, it seems to work fine at all zoom levels with all pdf viewers I tested.
All I did was selecting the white background (fuzzy select tool) and "deleting" it, using GIMP.Try this picture instead: [image: transparent background]

Answer (score 1):

You graphics is not actually a proper png image.  Check the following for the variants.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{graphicx,tikz}
%\immediate\write18{convert whale.png -transparent white tmpc.png}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw=black,line width=0.1mm,minimum size=50mm] at (0,0){};
    \node (img) at (0,0)  {\includegraphics[scale = .1]{tmp.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

        \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[circle,draw=black,line width=0.1mm,minimum size=50mm] at (0,0){};
    \node (img) at (0,0)  {\includegraphics[scale = .2]{tmp1.png}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \includegraphics[width=50mm]{tmp.png}

\end{document}
```

The following image is the one where the edges are cropped using `paint`. 
[image]

Note that your image had a white background and so the corners are already drawn(thats typically the borders). You can check in the following output of the above code.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I have no time to test it yet but that's possible.