# minted package -shell-escape error

Tags: luatex, minted, code

I am using TeXStudio with LuaLaTeX on Windows 10. When I call `\usepackage{minted}` I get

`Package minted Error: You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. \usepackage`

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: In the Options>Configure TeXstudio, set the command of `lualtex` to `lualatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex` for example.

Comment: By adding the `-shell-escape` flag, does it add more flexibility? Or will it not run for other types of code?

Comment: @Superman Actually `-shell-escape` brings risk. See https://www.texdev.net/2009/10/06/what-does-write18-mean/ and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/20446/79060 .

Comment: @Superman @muzimuzhi M Despite the risk (relative minor when creating your own `.tex` files) you will need the `--shell-escape` command in order to access the `Pygments` library of `Python`.  Otherwise the use of the `minted` package is senseless. See the Requirements section of the manual.

Comment: @Superman Apparently the path statement is changed using LuaLaTeX under Windows. You can check that using the code `\documentclass[11pt]{article}  \usesepackage{shellesc}  \begin{document}  \ShellEscape{path > path.txt} \end{document}` Compare the content of *path.txt* to the actual path in `cmd` of Windows.