# Compile and include a document from within a document

Tags: compiling, pdfpages

I am aware that this question seems a bit strange, but is there a way to compile and insert a document from within another document?

Let me explain exactly what I mean by this: I want to insert pages from another document into a document to show and comment on them. However, it would be important to me that this "embedded document" is compiled at the same time as the main document and does not have to already exist. I am aware that otherwise I could simply use the `\includepdf` command from `pdfpages`.

Comment: You can use `\immediate\write18` to execute a command, e.g compile another document, see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20444/what-are-immediate-write18-and-how-does-one-use-them

Comment: Are you also aware also of  `\input`  or `\include`   to include child parts and packages to use complete documents as this child parts  (i.e., docmute or standalone)?

Comment: I was aware of using `\input` to include a `.tex` file. I always use this to keep my code rather clean. So for example one `.tex` file for each section of the document. And in the "main" `.tex` file I would input them all and compile. But I wasn't aware that you could also include real documents with their own class and `\begin{document}`. This is great!

Comment: Just to be sure: Is this also possible with, for example, the `article` class or is it a `standalone` thing only?